# Magento 2 Customized Product

Tags: product, configurable-product, orders, magento2.2, simple-product

I'm struggling, I need some advice!

I want to create a form where a user can customize his order,

So it's a Cars Form, the user can chooses the model, the color, the brand, the quantity (a discount depends on the quantity) etc.  Each option has a unique price and image.

I created attributes for each of the options. 
In the form, each option is kinda related to the other, the color depends on the model, and the model depends on the brand.

I tried a simple product with customized options, each option has a price which is good but I can't add images for each option, I can't apply the discount and I can't relate the attributes .

Configurable Product or Bundle products require simple products which in my case are going to be hundreds, and I still can't apply the discount and can't relate the attributes to each other.

Any suggestion, please :(

Comment: Have you found a solution for your issue ?